# mod_proxy loading error when starting httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I compiled mod_proxy from scratch, added it to httpd.conf, yet when I start up apache I get this:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart; su - xamine; /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 60 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so: undefined symbol: proxy_lb_workers
                                                          [FAILED]
```

We've been racking our brains trying to figure out what causes this, without any luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I believe mod_proxy is actually built in several parts. mod_proxy.c and proxy_util.c.  I am assuming you used axps to build the modules?

Try following some of the advice in this guild: [Running a reverse proxy with apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies).

I would start by trying to build proxy_util using axps.

Comment: Unfortunately this is what we used. Any other thoughts?